# How to regenerate session without getting queued

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables, session-cookies

So I'd like to use session_regenerate_id() on certain ajax calls, but the call sometimes gets queued, which causes the user to get logged out.

How can I ensure that each time I regenerate a session, it will not get queued?

Comment: you can't. really. consider what happens. you fire off ajax calls #1 and #2. #1 gets delayed because someone severed a cable with a backhoe and #1 gets rerouted badly. #2 hits the server ok, session is regenned, and the client gets the new session id. At some point, #1 finally hits the server, and hey, this session ID doesn't exist, off to login you go.

Comment: ...and the (backhoe) "operator" never bothered "calling" first before "digging" @MarcB